# How to generate a two column and 21 row file with random values and the random() method in Python

Tags: python, random

I need to generate a two column and 21 row file with random values using file operations and random method in Python.

Example

```
Num0 0.283740
Num1 0.394882
Num3 0.384844
```

Read in the file, output the two columns in ascending order of random values 
Identify the min, max, median, mean of the values

must use the `random.random()` method

so far, I have:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
mylist = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randomint(0,100,size=21,1)), columns=list(' '))
mylist
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

mylist = pd.DataFrame({'a': [i for i in np.random.randint(0,100,size=21)], 'b':[i for i in np.random.randint(0,100,size=21)]} )
mylist
[image]